# Calling a Processing.py script from a VS code python script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, processing

I have written a python script in processing using its graphics package, however I would like to write a second script in VS code that can call this script in processing. Is there any way of doing this as I am unsure of how?
As well as this, is it possible to run processing python in VS code as this would make life a lot simpler? I have looked online but there is very limited information on this topic

Comment: Can you explain in detail how you want to call the file? There is no problem using Python in vscode. You can read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) for more information.

Comment: The code I have written is for a Rubik's cube simulator. It is currently a 3D cube that can be rotated. I would like to create a VS code algorithm, which randomly scrambles it and then generates a set of moves to solve it. Both this set of moves and the set of moves for scrambling it will be passed to the processing code which will then show these moves. I would prefer if the processing code were run  automatically and the code I have written doesn't appear. The processing code I have written will pass some info back. For information transfer I was thinking of using text files

Comment: The reason I would like to use VS code is that I need to create a GUI. And yes I know you can use python in VS code, I was just wondering about using Processing in VS code. Thanks